# Maven dependencies taking too much time to download in STS on Mac OS

Tags: spring-boot, maven, macos-monterey

My spring boot project creation taking too much time more than 5 hours still downloading for dependencies like Web, JPA, H2 and Thymeleaf.

I am using Mac OS Monterey(12.0.1), STS4(4.13.0) and using http://start.spring.io/

what could be the cause of failing to download such a small size dependencies

Comment: Are you running from plain command line or from inside your ide? First check to run on plain command line...

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Well issue has been resolved. I have just deleted my local maven repository and then it got resolved.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).